# Eclipse Plugin Development: How to open a TextEditor in java programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

```
    IPath path; //has some path
    IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);
    IWorkbenchPage page; //get current active page
    try {
         IJavaElement sourceJavaElement = JavaCore.create(file);
         ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)JavaUI.openInEditor(sourceJavaElement); //illegal argument exception here
        } catch (PartInitException | JavaModelException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I am using this code code to open the editor but it gives an illegal argument exception when openInEditor is called on sourceJavaElement.

Comment: I've also tried using https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F. It doesn't work either because IDE class is not available.

Comment: The `IDE` class is in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin so you must add that as a dependency of your plugin to use it.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace please

Comment: @greg-449: Thanks the problem is resolved.